# Finding the orthogonal complement where a single subspace is given

Tags: linear-algebra

For this question, am I doing it right so far?

Find the orthogonal complement of the given subspace $sp([1,2,-1]) in \Bbb R^3$

$a[1,2,-1].[x,y,z]$

= $ a+x, 2a+2y, -a+z$

$A = [1,1][2,2][-1,1]$

$A^T = [1,2,-1][1,2,1]$

After row reducing I get $[1,2,0][0,0,1]$

and then I let $x_2 = s$

$x_1 = -2s$

$x_3 = 0$

so I get $s[-2,1,0]$ as my final answer.

Comment: Just a hint:
The space generated by (1,2,-1) is a straight. The orthogonal compliment must to be a plane (try to imagine that), and, so, has dimension $2$

Comment: So I just repeat the process with the new set of vectors I found?

Comment: I confess that I didn't understood your process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by all the vectors orthogonal to $u=[1,2,-1]$

Finding the orthogonal compliment is finding a basis of unit vectors of $W$.

$$x+2y-z=0$$

$$x=-2y+z$$
Now,
$$(x,y,z)^T=(-2y+z,y,z)^T=(-2y,y,0)^T+(z,0,z)^T$$
$$=y(-2,1,0)^T+z(1,0,1)^T$$
So, the required vectors are $[-2,1,0]^T$ and $[1,0,1]^T$

Comment: What is T? does that mean transpose?

Comment: Yes, $T$ means transpose

Comment: What does the transpose of [-2,1,0] mean if its a 3 by 1 matrix?

Comment: Instead of writing as this $\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, I wrote $[-2,1,0]^T$. Both are same.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now, thanks. Could we also isolate for z and then plug it in? Would that be another way to do it?

Comment: Here I took $x=-2y+z$, but you can take either $y$ or $z$ as well

Comment: And is the sp([1,2,-1]) equivalent to saying the plane x+2y-z = 0?

Comment: Yes, it is equal

Comment: And just one more question. What would be $e_2$ or $e_3$ if the question was changed to $sp([e_2])$ or $sp([e_3])$?

Comment: Generally we take the vectors as $e_1=(1,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0),e_3=(0,0,1)$

Comment: alright so would $sp([e_1])$ be equivalent to $sp([1,0,0])$?

Comment: Yes, it is equal

Comment: And just going back to the original question, we have $(-2y+z,y,z)^T$ because we want only two variables right?

Comment: Yes, you need $y$ and $z$

Comment: So if the question was $sp([e_2])$ we know that y = 0, so how would we isolate for the other variables if they are also zero?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this is find the general vector $v=(x,y,z)$ satisfying $$\left<v,(1,2,-1)\right>=0$$
Using the usual inner product for $\mathbb{R^{3}}$, 
$$\left<v,(1,2,-1)\right>=0\Rightarrow x+2y-z=0$$

Comment: But part of the answer is sp([-2,1,0])

Comment: @dg123 Yes, it is, but there are other vectors besides those that are also orthogonal to $[1,2,-1]$.

Comment: so to find the other one do I just repeat the same process except with [-2,1,0]?